# Is it possible to disable the console or its keybind?

Tags: battlefield-4

I keep accidentally opening the console by pressing the accent grave/tilde key.

I know I can close it by pressing the button again.

**But how can I avoid opening it in the first place? Can you turn it off somehow? Can you change the key-binding for opening it?**

I use the key outside of gaming, so simply disabling it is not a solution.

This problem has been bothering me for years, but I have not yet found a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use a key remap program like [KeyRemapper](https://atnsoft.com/keyremapper/)**. 

This software offers the ability to save profiles, so you can easily switch between your default keybindings, and the ones you use in Battlefield.

- Download, install, and run the program.
- Click on the 'Add Profile' button (the document icon with a star superimposed).
- Name it something (like 'Battlefield4') and click 'OK'.
- Click on the '(double click to add)' line to add a key remap.
- Under 'Key or mouse button' select the key you're having trouble with (<kbd>~</kbd>).
- Select the option 'Block:', and select 'Full block, including with modifiers' if so desired.
- There you have it. You can switch to the default profile (aptly named 'Default profile') whenever you're out of the game to return the key its regular function.

  View this image for a graphical tutorial:

  [image]
- EDIT: As pointed out in a comment by *Roijan Eskor*, and as can be seen in the screenshot, the program allows for keybindings exclusive to preselected executables:

  > Restrict remapping and blocking to specific programs and windows. For
  >   instance, you can configure the software to allow the replacement of
  >   the X1 mouse button by Space only in program A and nowhere else.

Other possible programs you might want to use include [Sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/), [KeyTweak](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/keytweak.html), and [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Alternatively, depending on the type of keyboard you have, you might be able to pry of that particular button temporarily.

Comment: I notice in the screenshot there is a dropdown menu for where to apply the key modification. Could this be limited to inside the Battlefield executable? If so, that could solve the problem of having to toggle this on and off.

Comment: That's a really good point, and yes, it is. I had installed it only to see whether such a thing would work. I'll add the description of the software to my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot disable it nor can you can rebind the key. Solutions posted online suggest using a program to remap the key but in your scenario that would not work due to the fact that you use the key outside of gaming and disabling is not a valid solution.